# Android - using webview from activity 2 in activity 1

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

i have WebView in activity WebViewActivity, and some imagebuttons in main_activity.
Can u help me? I need when i click imagebutton1, it will open WebViewActivity ane open in WebView etc google.com. When i Click imagebutton2, it will open etc yahoo.com . Im new in programming, and im not anglophone (my english is bad because im from czech rep). Thanks for any help!

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
package com.tona.arcig;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        ImageButton imgbutton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        imgbutton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I like trains", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

WEBVIEWACTIVITY

```
package com.tona.arcig;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    }

}
```

ACTIVITY MAIN XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/suplovani"
            android:src="@drawable/suplovani" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/rozvrh"
            android:src="@drawable/rozvrh" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/prihlasovani"
            android:src="@drawable/prihlasovani" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/email"
            android:src="@drawable/email" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/email"
            android:src="@drawable/moodle" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/kdm"
            android:src="@drawable/jidelna" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/o_aplikaci"
            android:src="@drawable/about" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ACTIVITY WEBVIEW XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MANIFEST

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

STRINGS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="suplovani">Suplování</string>
    <string name="rozvrh">Rozvrh hodin</string>
    <string name="prihlasovani">Přihlašování do systému</string>
    <string name="email">Email</string>
    <string name="moodle">Moodle</string>
    <string name="kdm">KDM</string>
    <string name="o_aplikaci">O Aplikaci</string>
    <string name="app_name">Arcig.CZ</string>
    <string name="title_webview">Arcig.CZ</string>

</resources>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is basic skeleton of what should you do.
First you should pass some data depending on what button have you clicked(for example url string).

Next you should retrieve data and open appropriate url.
Here is how you can achieve this.

```
Intent openWebViewActivity = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class); // this is current Activity
openWebViewActivity.putExtra("web_url", "google.com"); // openWebViewActivity.putExtra("web_url", "yahoo.com");
startActivity(openWebViewActivity);
```

Now new Activity will be opened with appropriate intent.
And you can get url from this.

```
package com.tona.arcig;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    String urlToLoad = getIntent().getStringExtra("web_url");
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.loadUrl(urlToLoad);
}
}
```